# XAMPP ignores if header is already sent

Tags: php, http-headers

I am using XAMPP on Ubuntu 16.04.

The following test script

```
<?php
echo $hi;
header("Location: index.php");
```

should usually end with the following warning.

> Notice: Undefined variable: hi in test.php on line 2
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ..

However, when using XAMPP the header still redirects. If if comment the `header()`out, then the notice is shown.

I am using XAMPP as a test server, so its important for me that such warnings are shown.  Why is XAMPP ignoring that a header has already be send and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because you have output buffering turned on in the PHP configuration.

Call phpinfo() and check the value of `output_buffering`.

http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php